# fluid leaking through obstacles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, fluid-simulation

[image]I'm a beginner to blender, so please ignore my mistakes and be kind enough to guide me through this :)

I've scene this question before, but never got a satisfactory answer. I'm working on two animations, a over shot water wheel, and an Archimedes screw.
 My problem is, the fluid simulation does not work the way I want it to be.    when I bake it with the fluid it starts leaking through the solid object, even though i made it an obstacle . I tried baking it with a higher resolution and thicker walls, but i could not get the expected results.

Is there any way to stop this ? please help me to solve this

[image: Archimedes screw]

Comment: It is usually about resolution, try adding a subsurf modifier before the fluid and/or increasing the res in the domain fluid settings.